# HTTP auth on Python not working

Tags: python, http

so im trying to access this website using httpbasicauth but it's not working, here's the code that I'm using:

```
res = requests.head(url1, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, passw))
print (res)
print (res.headers.get('Location'))
```

and i get this output

```
<Response [302]> #this means that you are redirected to another page
http://some.page.it.redirects.you.to.if.you.aren't.logged.in.com
```

I know that the username and password are correct but it doesn't send me to the page it would if i were logged in on the browser.

The website says it's powered by http://openacs.org/ , i don't know if that matters.

Comment: Jose, that is a normal response. The page will respond with a "Set-Cookie" header (that has your auth cookies), and an `HTTP 302` to redirect you to the landing page. Look at an example by using `Firefox`. Press `F12` to open the dev console then click on the network tab and complete a successful login

Comment: but the Location label on the header, the one that tells me where it redirects me to, isn't redirecting me to the landing page from when you log in, it's redirecting me to `website.com/login`, the page it will send u to log in again if you put in your password wrong. Basically, i get the same result whether i put the right or the wrong credentials

Comment: use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox to see what information browser sends in request (headers, etc.) - and then use the same in your code.

Comment: Jose, is it actually using `basic authentication`? In other words, when you connect in your web browser does a username and password dialog pop up or is there a form embedded inside the page? Most pages; gmail.com, yahoo.com, wikipedia.org, etc. use form authentication and not basic authentication.